# How do I get my ajax to work with my quantity amount?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have added this quanity field to my woocommerce shop, however the add to cart ajax is not working the way it should be. I have ajax for product archive enabled on woocommerce setting, but still nothing. Is there a way to incorporate it with my functions?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );

function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
  if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && !$product->is_sold_individually() ) {
    $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
    $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
    $html .= '</form>';
  }
  return $html;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more like what you expecting but what happening. I believe that the functionality is working but instead of AJAX now it's working on form submission and page got refreshing, am I right?

Comment: Yes, when I select my quantity amount, click add to cart, page refreshes, I do not want it to refresh at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2);

function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link($html, $product)
{

    if ($product && $product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && !$product->is_sold_individually()) {
        woocommerce_quantity_input(array(), $product);
    }
    return $html;
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'update_quantity_attribute');
function update_quantity_attribute()
{
?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        let simpleProductInput = document.querySelectorAll('.product-type-simple .quantity > input');

        simpleProductInput.forEach(dom => {
            dom.addEventListener('input', e => {
                e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('data-quantity', e.target.value);
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

**Explanation: `quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link`**

In function `quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` refactored only to render quantity input field using the WooCommerce helper function `woocommerce_quantity_input`.

Function Source: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1668

This function is used to generate the HTML of the quantity input element and it accepts three parameters.

1. The first one is used overrides HTML attributes
2. The second argument is which accepts either `null` or object of the class `WC_Product`
3. Finally, the third parameter accepts boolean if it's true (default value) it will echo the content instead of returning the content.

**Explanation: `update_quantity_attribute`**

This function is responsible for overriding the cart button's data attribute `data-quantity` and JS is ES6 one as we used the `let` keyword and fat arrow method `=>`.

1. `document.querySelectorAll('.product-type-simple .quantity > input')` using this method `querySelectorAll` which return all matched dom elements into an array.
2. `simpleProductInput.forEach` loop through each DOM element.
3. Attach an event listener `input` using `dom.addEventListener` which will trigger on changing the value of the quantity input.
4. `e.target` selects the `input` DOM element and we called it's property `parentElement` which returns the DOM of its parent element.
5. Select the next sibling element i.e. add to cart button using the DOM method `nextElementSibling`
6. Override add to cart button attribute `data-quantity` with the `input` value.